# Selenium Grid doesn't work with more than one session

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, firefox, safari, selenium-grid

I'm using Selenium grid with a couple of virtual machines. So each machine is one node.

I'm trying to start a selenium test that will end up on one of the machines (due to capabilities) and then start the same test again at the same time. So the same test should be running in two instances on the same node.

If I do this in Chrome, it will finish the first test and then start the second test. In Firefox it will open two browsers, but often one of the tests will randomly get connection errors. In Safari it's like Chrome except sometimes it will open just a blank browser.

I have maxSessions on 3 in my node configuration files. So I don't see why this doesn't work with 3 tests at the same time. The tests themselves run fine. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you consider sharing your work with us? Thanks

Comment: Did you find any solution? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In Grid Console, You can check, how many chrome instances available on the node. By default, 5 chrome, 5 firefox and 1 IE instances available.
There is options called `maxInstances` by which you can limit no of same type of browser available. `MaxSession` will limit the no of parallel session. But if you set 'maxInstances' as 1 for chrome. It will launch only one chrome at time. 
If you want to run 3 chrome at a time then you config file should contains 'maxInstances' and 'maxSessions' as 3. Please check and let us know.